# C#のWebRequestクラスでSO_REUSEADDRを設定したい

Tags: c#, .net

C#のWebRequestクラスでSO_REUSEADDRを設定したいです。
MSDNを見たところ、ソケットを取得したりオプションを設定するインターフェースがありませんでしたが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT`になりますが、`ServicePointManager.ReusePort`を`true`に設定すれば要件が満たせるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます!ポート枯渇問題で困っていたので助かりました！